Will Hydrogen Peroxide Remove Sulphites From Vinegar?
I've been using a couple of drops of 2% hydrogen peroxide to remove sulphites from wine.
I'm tempted to try the same thing on malt vinegar, since that's a fermented product and likely to have sulphites in it. But searching for "vinegar and peroxide" produces many dire warnings against ever mixing the two.
Will it remove the sulphites?
Will it make peracetic acid?

Be careful ! Any excess of H2O2 must absolutely be absent from drinkable liquids. Even the risk of drinking dilute solutions of H2O2 should be avoided. Why remove sulphites from wine and/or from vinegar ?

@Maurice There is the Swiss liquid formula "Sanosil", treating small volumes of questionable drinking water for 30min-4h, based on hydrogen peroxide and silver salts, dosed IIRC some15-20 drops per 1 L. I would not be so anxious.  AFAIK, there exists alergic reaction to sulfites, so for such a people, H2O2 is less evil.

I don't believe that sulphites can exist in vinegar at all, given its acidity. (Wine is another story.)

I assume that if then in form of mainly  SO2(aq) + HCO3-(aq) ( pKa1 = 1.81 ). But that is a detail, considering "total sulfites".

@IvanNeretin Ooh, that's interesting! How sure are you of that? The sulphite-concerned often say that some vinegars have them in. Is that in fact impossible?

@Maurice Really? 2 drops of 2% hydrogen peroxide in a glass of wine is dangerous? Can you point me at a relevant reference?

I assume SO2/HCO3- is added to wine as the conservant for long term storage, mainly to protect it against oxidation to acetic acid, becoming vinegar. If the wine is supposed to be used for wine vinegar production,  SO2 would not be added.

@Poutnik You'd hope wouldn't you? but I think that fermentation itself can produce the damned things, so "no added sulphites" is not really good enough for my purposes.

The question is not if Yes or No, but how much and how much matters.

@Poutnik Agreed

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
